# How Can I Bulk Import ShoppingCart Price Rule SKU'S into Conditions And Actions

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, grouped-products, sku

I want to add bulk SKU's in Conditions and Actions,  is any possible to bulk import sku's to Conditions and Actions,

Screen Shots: [image]
[image]

Comment: Try free extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-coupon-with-shopping-cart-price-rules.html

Comment: Your Suggestion Extension good, but i need bulk import condition sku's look like above screen shots. How can i bulk import sku's in conditions

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN DO THIS FOR FREE - No MODULES NEEDED - its rather simple really!

There are a couple of modules that say they do this, I didnt want to pay any money out - so I found a simple way of doing this via CSV files.

```
1 - goto your database using PHPMYADMIN 
2 - find the table: ‘salesrule’ and export all the values as CSV 
3 - Downlaod OPENOFFICE CALC and open the downloaded file 
(DO NOT USE EXCEL AS IT BREAKS THE FORMAT WHEN UPLOADING BACK - SILLY but true!) 
4 - Look at what has been generated - familarise your self with the fields. 
5 - pay attention to the column ‘actions_serialized’ - this is where the SKU for your product will be found 
6 - Ammend the file to your needs making sure you update the SKU and name etc.
```

This will all depend on what your rules are. 
Mine were simple, creating a fixed percentage discount based on qty in the cart 
I used this method to add prices effortlessly

Hope it will be helpfull for you.

Comment: good one, but not suitable for me, because mine distinct form your simple one.

Comment: Actually i need how can i bulk import sku's